# Where is AddConfigurationStore and AddOperationalStore in IdentityServer4 v2.3.2

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

So I create a project based on quickstart of [identityserver.io](http://identityserver.io), and I did everything according to tutorial.
But I don't have

> AddConfigurationStore
>
> AddOperationalStore

on

> services.AddIdentityServer

Can anybody help me ?

It is worth mentioning that they are available in IdentityServer4 v2.2.0 and in IdentityServer release [page](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/releases), I don't see any thing about this change.

This is my configuration code :

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`AddConfigurationStore` and `AddOperationalStore` are extensions in the *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection* namespace, but located in the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` assembly.

You'll have to add the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` NuGet package to your project.

Comment: Now I have problem with this : .AddConfigurationStore(a=> a.UseSqlServer())
there is not any UseSqlServer on a object.

Comment: @jsDevia That's another package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: What if I don't want to use EF but still have my own user store?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to make sure you use version 4.0.0 of IdentityServer4.EntityFramework

Comment: How does that translate to the Duende (a.k.a. IDS5)?